# Create a row for each date in a range, and add 1 for each day within a date range for a record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Suppose I have a date range, @StartDate = 2022-01-01 and @EndDate = 2022-02-01, and this is a reporting period.

In addition, I also have customer records, where each customer has a LIVE Date and a ServiceEndDate (or ServiceEndDate = NULL as they are an ongoing customer)

Some customers may have their Live Date and Service end date range extend outside of the reporting period range. I would only want to report for days that they were a customer in the period.

| Name | LiveDate | ServiceEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 2021-10-11 | 2022-01-13 |
| Mark | 2022-11-13 | 2022-02-15 |
| Andy | 2022-01-02 | 2022-02-10 |
| Rob | 2022-01-09 | 2022-01-14 |

I would like to create a table where column A is the Date (iterating between every date in the reporting period) and column B is a sum of the number of customers that were a customer on that date.

Something like this

| Date | NumberOfCustomers |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 3 |
| 2022-01-03 | 3 |
| 2022-01-04 | 3 |
| 2022-01-05 | 3 |
| 2022-01-06 | 3 |
| 2022-01-07 | 3 |
| 2022-01-08 | 3 |
| 2022-01-09 | 4 |
| 2022-01-10 | 4 |
| 2022-01-11 | 4 |
| 2022-01-12 | 4 |
| 2022-01-13 | 4 |
| 2022-01-14 | 3 |
| 2022-01-15 | 3 |

And so on until the end the @EndDate

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join your table to a calendar table containing all the dates you need:

```
WITH calendar
     AS (SELECT Cast('2022-01-01' AS DATETIME) AS d
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(day, 1, d)
         FROM   calendar
         WHERE  d < '2022-02-01')
SELECT d        AS "Date",
       Count(*) AS NumberOfCustomers
FROM   calendar
       INNER JOIN table_name
               ON d BETWEEN livedate AND COALESCE(serviceenddate, '9999-12-31')
GROUP  BY d;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73b273cad2ab9d1f9a76956a4b73e295)

Comment: OP says `ServiceEndDate` could be NULL.

Comment: OP should really include that in their sample data mind, @Serg .

Answer (score 4):

I would personally suggest using a Tally, rather than an rCTE, as a Tally is *significantly* more performant.

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES('Tom ',CONVERT(date,'2021-10-11 '),CONVERT(date,'2022-01-13')),
            ('Mark',CONVERT(date,'  2022-11-13'),CONVERT(date,' 2022-02-15')),
            ('Andy',CONVERT(date,'  2022-01-02'),CONVERT(date,' 2022-02-10')),
            ('Rob ',CONVERT(date,'2022-01-09 '),CONVERT(date,'2022-01-14')))V(Name,LiveDate,ServiceEndDate);
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20220101',
        @EndDate date = '20220201';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)) 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --up to 1,000 days
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate) AS Date
    FROM Tally T)
SELECT D.Date,
       COUNT(YT.[Name]) AS NumberOfCustomers
FROM Dates D
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON D.[Date] >= YT.LiveDate
                               AND (D.[Date] <= YT.ServiceEndDate
                                OR  YT.ServiceEndDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY D.[Date]
ORDER BY D.[Date];
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Note that then results don't reflect your expected results, I suspect your expected results are wrong. For example you have 2 people live on 2022-01-01, however, there is only 1 person who is live on that date: Tom.

This solution will also never have Mark as "live" (the rCTE method in the other answer won't either) as their end date is **before** their Live date. If someone can have their service end before it started, I would suggest you have a data quality issue, and you should be adding a `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT` to the table to ensure that value of `ServiceEndDate` is `>= LiveDate`.