# Adding row for every date between two dates in SQL

Tags: sql, date, ssms

I have a table with values for a start and end date. If the start and end date is not the same, I want to duplicate the rows for the dates in between, so that each date has his own row with the same information.
Of course I have read many solutions, but could still not figure out how to deal with my problem. I do not want to make a calendar table to help solve this problem. Therefore, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70984357/create-a-row-for-each-date-in-a-range-and-add-1-for-each-day-within-a-date-rang) does not solve my problem.

Here is a minimal reproducable example:

```
CREATE TABLE
  myTable (
    [SchoolId] int,
    [StartDate] date,
    [EndDate] date,
    [SomeBit] bit,
    [BigId] bigint,
);

INSERT INTO
  myTable (
    [SchoolId],
    [StartDate],
    [EndDate],
    [SomeBit],
    [BigId]
  )
VALUES
  (1, '20150101', '20150104', 0,  437457324555),
  (2, '20150101', '20150101', 1,  4573467234),
  (3, '20150102', '20150102', 0,  45756654565),
  (4, '20150102', '20150103', 1,  4564576754),
  (5, '20150105', '20150106', 1, 54745753)
;

SELECT * FROM myTable;
```

In this example, I would want an outcome that has four lines with schoolId 1, Somebit 0 and BigId 437... (so copying the data except for the start and end date) with start dates 2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-03 and 2015-01-04. The value of the end date won't be used.

As for rows 2 and 3 the start and end date are the same, nothing should be added.
For rows 4 and 5 one row each should be added with startdates 2015-01-03 and 2015-01-05 respectively.

| SchoolID | StartDate | SomeBit | BigID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20150101 | 0 | 437457324555 |
| 1 | 20150102 | 0 | 437457324555 |
| 1 | 20150103 | 0 | 437457324555 |
| 1 | 20150104 | 0 | 437457324555 |
| 2 | 20150101 | 1 | 4573467234 |
| 2 | 20150102 | 0 | 45756654565 |
| 4 | 20150102 | 1 | 4564576754 |
| 4 | 20150103 | 1 | 4564576754 |
| 5 | 20150105 | 1 | 54745753 |
| 5 | 20150106 | 1 | 54745753 |

In the real table, I am dealing with 100.000s of rows. I work with T-SQL in SSMS.

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

Comment: Just `JOIN` to your calendar table and you have a row for every date. If you don't have a calendar table, why not? Take the time to invest to creating one.

Comment: I have reasons not to create a calender table here. I therefore am looking for a different solution. I know that SSMS it not important, but with a similar question I recently was asked what program I used, so I tend to add it in the question nowadays.

Comment: Also, if I had a calender table, it would still not be clear for me how to duplicate the other data to the null fields after the right join. I would guess something with lagging, but it's not totally straight-forward for me.

Comment: *"I have reasons not to create a calender table here."* And what reasons are those? It *is* what you need.

Comment: What `NULL` values? There's no `NULL`s in your data and you don't mention them in the question either.

Comment: I do not wish to share. But if I need those, are you willing to share a solution for this using a calendar table?

Comment: If I right join the calender table on the Startdate of my MRE, I would have null values for schoolId, SomeBit and BigId for example with Startdate 2015-01-03 as it does not appear in the StartDate column.

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result? (I.e. provide a complete [mcve].)

Comment: What's wrong with `JOIN dbo.Calendar C ON YT.StartDate >= C.CalendarDate AND YT.EndDate <= C.CalendarDate`...? Why would you get `nULL` values from that?

Comment: jarlh, what do you want to be specified? I actually did describe quite specificly my desired result right?

Comment: Thanks Thom, I will try your solution with the on-the-fly calendar mentioned in many other questions. :)

Comment: I tried the solution suggested by Thom does not even yield a solution on my MRE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution for ISO SQL is :

```
SELECT *, DATEADD(day, value, [StartDate]) 
FROM   myTable AS T
       CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(DAY, [StartDate], [EndDate]))
```

GENERATE_SERIES has been add to SQL ISO standard and can be found in PostGreSQL and MS SQL Server.

This example if for MS SQL Server.

Comment: I use MS SQL Server and checked for updates. It's up to date. I read in Microsoft documentation that this GENERATE_SERIES function needs a compability level of at least 150, which is not possible with updated version of 2019. I then downloaded SMSS 2022 and that works fine.

Comment: None of GENERATE_SERIES, DATEADD, DATEDIFF or CROSS APPLY is ISO SQL.